# Background task SystemTriggerType.SmsReceived won't triggered

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm testing tasks in background windows phone 8.1 but the trigger `SystemTriggerType.SmsReceived` is not working for me . Has anyone managed to make it work ?

I used [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9) of the MS background task , but only the original version worked.

Replaces this:

```
var task = BackgroundTaskSample.RegisterBackgroundTask ( BackgroundTaskSample.SampleBackgroundTaskEntryPoint, BackgroundTaskSample.SampleBackgroundTaskName ,new SystemTrigger ( SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange , false) ,null) ;
```

On This :

```
var task = BackgroundTaskSample.RegisterBackgroundTask (BackgroundTaskSample.SampleBackgroundTaskEntryPoint, BackgroundTaskSample.SampleBackgroundTaskName , new SystemTrigger ( SystemTriggerType.SmsReceived , false) ,null) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SystemTriggerType.SmsReceived` is only available to 1st party applications. It's not available to 3rd party application developers.

I'm sorry for us not having the preliminary documentation clarify this. Hopefully the final version of the SDK documentation for Universal Apps (Windows Runtime) will clarify this.

Comment: Why isn't it available for 3rd party apps? Why don't you remove these stupid limitations?