# SystemTriggerType SmsReceived Task is not working in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, background-task

I have created a simple task to be triggered when sms is received in windows phone 8.1 universal app but it is not working? any one else has the same issue? here is my code.

```
await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        taskBuilder.Name = "SMSTask";

        //GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync();
        //GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger trigger = new GattCharacteristicNotificationTrigger(GattCharacteristic);

        SystemTrigger systemTrigger1 = new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange, false);
        BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder1 = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        taskBuilder1.Name = "TestTask";
        taskBuilder1.SetTrigger(systemTrigger1);
        taskBuilder1.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(TestTask.TestTask).FullName;
        taskBuilder1.Register();

        SystemTrigger systemTrigger = new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.SmsReceived, false);
        taskBuilder.SetTrigger(systemTrigger);

        taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(SMSTask.SMSTask).FullName;
        taskBuilder.Register();
        lblMessage.Text = "both task registered";
```

In above code there are 2 task one is for timezone which is working fine other is for sms receive which is not working when I receive sms in my mobile device

Answer (score 1):

According to this Windows Dev Center forum thread, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5c8836cf-4acd-479a-9847-f60b4be7e146/background-task-systemtriggertypesmsreceived-wont-triggered?forum=wpdevelop, it appears that this trigger will only be fired for Mobile Operator apps (I'm guessing these would be whitelisted by the OS somehow, not sure) on Windows Phone 8.1.

Also see this question asked in [Background task SystemTriggerType.SmsReceived won't triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123295/background-task-systemtriggertype-smsreceived-wont-triggered) which was asked while the documentation for Windows Phone 8.1 was not final.  The documentation for this restriction still doesn't appear to be clear on this as it should be.  If someone knows the best way to submit this feedback for MSDN documentation I would recommend doing so.

Comment: Looks like one way to submit feedback is to say "No" to "Was this page helpful?" which then asks for comments.  This however seems a bit extreme since you might find a MSDN page useful but just might have feedback to improve it.  Also you can only submit feedback once per page (for a given login) it seems.  I've submitted the SMSReceived support clarity feedback in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx.